# Moving a label inside another label and detect it using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

Let say I want to move a label inside another empty label or empty box, can I use an empty `UILabel`? How can I detect that my label is 'over' my empty label?

My app will have let say 5 different numbers, 1 being the right answer. I want to be able to put these numbers in an empty box and pop up a message saying a good or bad message.

At this point my label is moving but I don't detect it when it comes over my empty label.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if label == "" {
your action 
} else {
another action or nothing
}
```